# Providing package-private methods for testing?

Tags: java, testing

I'm writing the following class:

```
public class MyClass{

    private final MyAnotherClass[][] anotherClasses;

    public MyClass(//args){
        //initialization
    }

    //...
}
```

I'd like to test this class, but wouldn't like to provide any methods exposing its iternal state (`anotherClasses` array in this case). The test is going to test the state of the array, so we have to access it.

Is it considering as a good practice to provide a method, say

```
MyAnotherClass[][] getAnotherClasses(){
    retun anotherClasses;
}
```

with `package-private` visibility to use it ***only*** for testing? I'm kind of not sure about that. We introduce some annoying coupling between the class and its test...

Maybe there's a better approach to deal with that?

Comment: Testing should only verify the external behavior of the class under test. If you end up replacing the double-array with some other data structure that more efficiently gives the same result, you shouldn't need to re-write the tests as long as it does give that same result. If you're going to rely on internal state in your tests (not a good idea for the reasons I just outlined) you may as well use reflection to get that array.

Comment: @hexafraction true for this particular case, but it frequently happens that the public methods of a class are not fine-grained enough to allow good unit testing.

Comment: @CPerkins If you can't hit all of your private methods, then you're probably not testing all of your requirements.  If you are... then you don't need the private method.

Comment: Testing for anything private is going into too much detail.  Frequently people don't write enough tests, but you can get into a situation where there are too many tests.  If you're in a situation where every change you make causes tests to fail, then all of your tests are just noise.  It's hard to identify what is a broken requirement (in which case you probably don't want to edit the unit test) and what is just an implementation detail that no longer matters.  Unit testing is easy, but doing it right is a bit of an art.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, it is not good practice to test non-public methods. But sometimes if it is really needed for me, I'm using `@VisibleForTesting` annotation from guava.